# Copernicus' Theorem

Tags: geometry

I am trying to understand the proof of Copernicus' Theorem.

> Consider two circles of radii R and R/2 with the smaller one rolling
>   inside the bigger circle without slipping. Copernicus' Theorem states
>   a surprising result that a point on the circumference of the small
>   circle traces a straight line segment - a diameter of the big circle,
>   to be precise.

If found the following useful [resource](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Copernicus.shtml) with a proof.

I was able to understand everything of the proof besides the first argument:

> Assume point M on the small circle has previously occupied the
>   position of point N on the large circle. Since there is no slipping,
>   arcs PM (on the small circle) and PN (on the large circle) have
>   exactly the same length.

[image]

I can't conclude that the arcs of PM and PN (marked as red) should have the same lenght. Is there a proof for that?

[image]

Comment: John Baez has a few blog posts on curves traced by rolling circles, and in particular the entry [here](http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rolling/rolling_3.html) describes the arrangment you're interested in. (Plus animations!)

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks for your link! I just read it and he states `The arc PN of the big circle has the same length as the arc PM of the small circle, since they are both the distance rolled between times t and t.` Where `t` is the time of my bottom left picture and `t.` the time of the bottem right picture. But I still do not understand that argument.

Comment: Isn't that the definition of "no slipping"?  Equality of distance?  If not, what is the definition of "no slipping"?

Comment: @BrianTung I only found the definition of no slipping here: http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/rolling-without-slipping.html which says that there is no tangential l movement at the contact point (for P or N). This means the circle only moves through rotation. I can't see how one can conclude from this fact that the both arcs lengts from PM and PN are equal.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't see how to demonstrate that, or that you don't think it's true?

Comment: @BrianTung I mean that I do not know how to prove it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof.

Have the point Q be on the opposite side of point N.

Statement: The arcs PN and PM have the same length when the smaller circle rolls without slipping.

Proof:
Assume, to the contrary, that the arcs PN and PM do not have the same length. Then there is no bijection between the points on the arcs PN and PM. As an aide, we can express this (albeit incorrectly) as a function $f: PN→PM$. There are two cases.

Case I: Arc PN has points that correspond to the same point on arc PM.

Case II: Arc PN has all points not correspond to some points on arc PM.

Case I: Let the arc PN have a length greater than or equal to $π$. The smaller circle rolls $2π$ radians or onwards. However, the arc length of PM cannot be greater than the smaller circle’s circumference. From $S=θr$, we have $S=2π \cdot \frac{1}{2}=π$.  Therefore, the point Q is where the arc length is longest. This is precisely the arc length of QN, a contradiction.

Case II: Let the arc PN have a length less than $\pi$. The smaller circle must not touch the larger circle at some point for its arc length to be $\pi$, violating no slipping. ∎